# Data source for probable location of rough primary residences over the globe?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I'm looking for a data source that would allow me to generate a lat/long that is "probable location of a human's home". I'd hope that if I ran it ~8 billion times, it'd give me something 'similar' to the distributions of humans on the planet at any given time.

I'm comfortable with the data being very rough — it'd be ideal if I could get single digit number of different lat/long 'bins' for a major metropolis for example (eg. the east side of NYC has an X% chance of hosting a human, the west side Y%), but not a requirement — whole city level 'bins' would be fine too.

I live in the UK, so I'm reasonably familiar with [the ONS](https://www.ons.gov.uk/), which I'm sure has data I can use for my country, but is there anything global I could lean on?

Comment: Do you mean a population density map like this one? luminocity3d.org/WorldPopDen/

Comment: Exactly like that @mcsoini! And it has a link to the data right there too  Thank you! (Feel free to make a proper answer, if you like!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As determined in the comments, what you are looking for is a "population density map", a search term which gives plenty of results. You could start from here: [luminocity3d.org/WorldPopDen/](https://luminocity3d.org/WorldPopDen/) and the data sources of that map.